# CSS in Django 2.0

Tags: css, django, bootstrap-4

Here is a HTML code that my teammate wrote that uses CSS/Bootstrap. 
How do I render it in Django? 
It works when I open the file as HTML but I am not able to render it in Django.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">



<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="vendor/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/stylish-portfolio.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Why are you not able? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I have these are the errors [08/Aug/2018 07:52:43] "GET /vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2582
Not Found: /vendor/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css
Not Found: /css/stylish-portfolio.min.css
[08/Aug/2018 07:52:43] "GET /vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css 
[08/Aug/2018 07:52:43] "GET /vendor/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2615
[08/Aug/2018 07:52:43] "GET /css/stylish-portfolio.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2552
Not Found: /js/stylish-portfolio.min.js
Not Found: /js/contact_me.js
Not Found: /vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js

Comment: [08/Aug/2018 07:52:43] "GET /vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css

Comment: How is that an error? Looks like a simple line from an Apache access log

Comment: You have to go in the documentation, or read some tutorials on this. You haven't linked the fonts and css properly. The documentation tells you where to store them and how to links them in your template. There are also many tutorials. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

in your settings put:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "path/to/your/static/folder"
```

in your root urls.py put after urlpatterns:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

and create static folder in your root folder of project, and copy all your static files there.
After that in your template:

```
{% load static %}

<link href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Use like this.
If you have another questions, please read:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/